# PHP Turn back time

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to turn back the time 10 seconds before current time and output in this format date('H/i/s')

How can I do this ?

I dont want to get current time then remove 10 seconds from time .

Thanks

Comment: For what reasons do you not want to deduct 10 seconds from something like `time()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo date('H/i/s', time()-10);
```

Comment: This answer is no longer valid

Comment: I thought the user edited the question to mean they wanted to change the system time.

Comment: @NullUserException - Then why did they accept the answer? I am confused too; it seems like this answer is doing exactly what the user didn't want (subtracting from `time()`.... which does seem like the correct thing to do btw).... but they accepted it??

Answer (score 5):

I personally try to avoid playing directly with the `time()` value, for reasons when trying to add or subtract days/weeks/etc. with leap years, etc. For all practical purposes, `strtotime()` is always reliable :

```
echo date('H/i/s', strtotime('-10 seconds', time())); // time() - 10 seconds
```

** **EDIT** **

Why `time() - 10` is [not good](http://codepad.viper-7.com/n4SUGP)?

```
<?php
// this is my timezone, but it applies to any DST zones....
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');

$time = strtotime('2010-11-07 02:00:05');

var_dump(date(DATE_RFC822, $time - 10));
var_dump(date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime('-10 seconds', $time)));
```

The output of this is

```
string(29) "Sun, 07 Nov 10 01:59:55 -0500"
string(29) "Sun, 07 Nov 10 01:59:55 -0400"
```

Note how the UTC changes in the second example? Where it is not entirely correct and should be `Sun, 07 Nov 10 02:59:55 -0500` *(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834353/php-how-do-i-convert-a-server-timestamp-to-the-users-timezone) to reset it back to the correct UTC)* subtracting 10 to `time()` is even worst! It returns a timestamp off by 1 hour in time. This could lead to potential data errors, etc.

The same thing applies adding and subtracting days and months; directly manipulating `time()` is simply not a good idea and `strtotime()` will always return the correct timestamp for the given time manipulation. Period.

Comment: "value, for reasons when trying to add or subtract days/weeks/etc. with leap years, etc" --- time() is just a number of seconds since unix epoch and has nothing to do with leap years etc. It grows monotonously regardless leap year or anything else.

Comment: I know that, and now you get `echo $time - strtotime('-10 seconds', $time);`. But only 10 seconds left, not 3610. The issue is in the date formatting, not in its calculation. Time flows monotonously, and if 10 seconds left, then difference is 10. If no - fix your date() function.

Comment: @zerkms, `echo $time - strtotime('-10 seconds', $time);` echo 3610 for me while `echo $time - ($time - 10);` echo 10... the latter is wrong (where $time is "Sun, 07 Nov 10 02:00:05" or course). The problem is not that it doesn't matter on most case, the problem is that it does on certain "unpredictable" ones.

Comment: Timestamp is a number of second since 1 Jan 1970. It grows **monotonously** second by second. If 10 seconds left, then timestamps are differ by **10**. Point. You have an issue with **date formatting**. Your date function has no idea about summer and non-summer time - that is why you trying to cheat.

Comment: @zerkms, you can justify however you want, but direct manipulation of time does not guarantee to return the correct timestamps all the time in every timezones. Time may increment *monotonously* as you say, but there is a time change in DST for a fact, and `time() - 10` during that change yields incorrect timestamps, whereas `strtotime('-10 seconds')` is **always** correct. You won't win here.

Comment: **Each timestamp is correct**. Each timestamp is existing in each timezone. "and time() - 10 during that change yields incorrect timestamps" --- nope. Timestamp is correct, but the function that formats that timestamp into human readable format - is not. The weak chain here is `date()`, which cannot determine whether time is summer or winter, and `not time()`.

Comment: @zerkms, this is exaclty what I'm saying. Direct manipulation `$time() - 10 = 1289113195` where `strtotime('-10 seconds', $time) = 1289109595` ... do you see here? The first one, how wrong it is? This has nothing to do with `date()` but with the calculation itself. I told you, you won't win here.

Answer (score 3):

To change system time, you need to call the OS' API to change the time. On Linux, you can do this with the `date` command:

```
date MMDDhhmmYYYY.ss
```

For example, `date 092619222010.30` will set the date and time to `Sep 26 2010 19:22:30`. On PHP you could try to use the [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)<sup>1</sup> function to do that.

```
$stamp = date('mdHiY.s', time()-10);
system("date $stamp");
```

<sup>1</sup> PHP runs as the same user as Apache if it's running under mod_php (the default setup). This usually means you won't have permissions to do it. If that happens to be the case, you can get around it by calling another script or program that *can* change the time.

Comment: This is not the answer he wanted. He was asking for a solution in PHP, which is usually running as the same user as the webserver does. Even with system() he will not be able to change the system time.

Comment: @halfdan Well, what do you suggest?

Comment: See the accepted answer. He just wants to output the time form 10secs ago, not change the system time. So why not just substract 10seconds from time()?

Comment: @halfdan That's what I assumed (and answered) initially. But the OP edited the question and added the following: "I dont want to get current time then remove 10 seconds from time ."

Comment: That's a little misleading, I agree. But his wording suggests that he isn't very experienced, so I concluded that he just wants to substract 10 seconds from the current time. (Didn't downvote you anyway, answer is still good)